# Simple Javascript redirection works with localhost testing and not with uploaded site

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a prototype site using a mamp server and the below redirection works fine but when I use it with my uploaded site its coming up with un recognised url. It is probably me being daft after too many hours of coding.

It is all stored in a folder as follows creativetreeAlpha/file here does it need this? The data (variable which is encoded) is coming through fine.

```
 //new code does not recognise url                                                        
 window.location="http://projectboard.php?emailid="+data;

 //old MAMP code works in my server
  window.location="http://localhost/creativetreelatest/projectboard.php?emailid="+data;
```

Comment: You are forgetting your domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://projectboard.php?emailid=...` is not a valid url.

Try something like:

```
window.location="http://yourDomain.com/projectboard.php?emailid=" + data;
```

Comment: aha so it would www.projectboard.php excuse if this is tosh but my brains fried.

Comment: cool will do, that make sense! i knew it was something simple my brain is fried from PHP and javascript all day!

Comment: @sherwoodbear `php` is not currently a valid top level domain. See http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db for valid TLDs. Are you trying to use a relative path to access your page?